# Adding text to fading background image

Tags: html, css

I'm using div that contains fading image and that div prevents me from writing any text on the image itself.

I tried adding `position: absolute;`, though centering the text was a bit problem but I didn't succeed.

```
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: url("https://climate.nasa.gov/assets/images_of_change/ioc_intro_image.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
}
```

**code snippet**

---

```css
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: url("https://climate.nasa.gov/assets/images_of_change/ioc_intro_image.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
}
```

```html
<div class="bg" data-aos="fade-up">
 <h1>
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 </h1>
</div>
```

How can I add text to my background picture so I'll be able to change the text margin in a responsive way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try positioning your background div absolute and bring content out of division.

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: url("https://climate.nasa.gov/assets/images_of_change/ioc_intro_image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg" data-aos="fade-up">
</div>
<h1>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</h1>
```